# How to reduce overall analysis duration in Sonarqube Analysis?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

My use case details are like below.
Sonarqube Version: 4.5.2
Ram: 16 GB
Code base size: in GBs
OS: Windows
Project Languages: Java, JavaScript
Project Type: Multi Module

Analysis takes half of the day like 12-13 hours. Need help in minimizing the same.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple things address here

- network latency - for the version you're running, you want to make sure the machine that performs the analysis is a close as possible on the network to your database
- database contention - in 4.5.2, the scanner talks directly to the database. If analyses of other projects are happening concurrently, they could be interfering with each other. You can remove this problem by upgrading to the new L.T.S. version, 5.6, which fully cuts the ties from the scanner to the database. In 5.6 analysis reports are generated by the SonarQube scanner, and submitted to the server, where they're queued for processing and handled serially
- Your project is just too darn big to analyze successfully in a reasonable amount of time. This may or may not be the case, but you should give it honest consideration, and potentially analyze components independently. Doing so would have the knock-on benefit of not reanalyzing the whole thing when one file in one module has changed. If you need to re-aggregate the results of the individual component analyses, you can do so with the Governance plugin($).